# How to resolve this error while making a http web GET request C#

Tags: c#, http, request, get

I need help with my `C#` Code for a GET Request
This is the code:

```
public class Class1
{
    private const string URL = "url";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // List data response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("?api_key=token").Result;  // Blocking call! Program will wait here until a response is received or a timeout occurs.
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Parse the response body.
            var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<DataObject>>().Result;  //Make sure to add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
            foreach (var d in dataObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.Name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }

        //Make any other calls using HttpClient here.

        //Dispose once all HttpClient calls are complete. This is not necessary if the containing object will be disposed of; for example in this case the HttpClient instance will be disposed automatically when the application terminates so the following call is superfluous.
        client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get:

> System.AggregateException: "One or more errors occurred. (Cannot
> deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type

Comment: It seems you are trying to deserialize a json server response into some `IEnumerable<DataObject>`, but the exception is telling you that that is not possible, due to a mismatch between the json data structure in the response and the type(s) hierarchy you want to serialize into. Solution is rather simple: Either make the json response message match exactly the structure of your deserialization target type(s). Or, if that's not possible, do it the other way round: Match the structure of your deserialization target type(s) exactly to the structure of the received json response message.

Answer (score 0):

You can do these steps to find which line makes the error and *improve your debug skill*:

**Step 1**: Open **Visual Studio**

**Step 2**: Press **Ctrl + Alt + E** to display **Exception Settings** windows at the bottom of Visual Studio

**Step 3**: Click to option **Common Language Runtime Exceptions** to display **tick (v)** sign

**Step 4**: Press `F5` to run program in **mode debug**

**Step 5**: Follow the **exception description** you will know which **line of code** makes the **error** and **fix** them